# Not Able to Add New iOS App, Create Bundle in iTunes connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Recently **I got ADMIN access** to my iTunesConnect account from Client.

While i was trying to add new app from **myApps**, i did not get any options to Add New iOS App or Create Bundle. as show in image 2

Could any one please suggest do we need to do anything from client side or my side.

immediate after login i got an notification regarding tax etc.. as shown in image 1

**Image 1 : Display un know notification**
[image: Image 1 : Display un know notification]

---

**Image 2 : Empty popUp**
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You team agent (the one who created your Apple Developer Account) has to sign in to the Apple Developer Portal and accept the new agreement before you can create new apps in iTunes Connect or submit updates to existing ones.

I assume from your description that this account belongs to one of your clients. Just inform him to login and accept the new agreement.

Comment: You are welcome. Note that the account creator has to accept the new license and not anyone with admin role (thats why you cannot accept it).

Comment: Amazing that those two would be related and that Apple of course would not show a helpful error message. Thanks anyway!